# Chasing the diagram of a natural transformation - I'm lost, please help

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

The purpose is to show that a vector space is canonically embedded in its double dual by showing that the collection of natural embeddings into the double duals is the data of a natural transformation from the identity functor to the double dual functor. Hence, showing the following diagram always commutes:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    V^{**} @>f^{**}>> W^{**}\\
    @A \overline{(\cdot)} AA @AA \overline{(\cdot)} A\\
    V @>>f> W
    \end{CD}$$

where $f$ is any linear transformation, $^{**}$ is the double dual functor, and $\overline{v}$ represents the natural image of a vector in the double dual (the natural embedding).

This is where I'm lost. I'm sure I'm supposed to be pushing an arbitrary element of $V$ along each of the arrows and verifying it reaches the same destination in $W^{**}$, but I'm just having trouble keeping track of all the manipulations that go on inside of this seemingly simple diagram. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JohnMa Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call the vertical map $i_V :V\to V^{**}$ (and similarly for $W$). By definition,

$$i_V( v ) (x^*)= x^*(v) \ \ \ \ \forall\ x^* \in V^*, v\in V.$$

Then

$$(f^{**} \circ  i_V) (v) (y^*) = i_V (v) (f^* y^*) = f^*y^* (v) = y^*(fv)$$

and

$$(i_W \circ f)(v) (y^*) = i_W(fv) (y^*) = y^*(fv).$$

Thus the diagram commutes.

Comment: Do your $y^*$'s and $x^*$'s refer to the same thing?

Comment: I try to use $x^* \in V^*$ and $y^* \in W^*$.@silvascientist

Comment: Writing the same with other symbols:  using $\,f^{**}(\Theta) = \psi\mapsto \Theta(\psi\circ f)\,$ for $\psi:W\to K$, we arrive to
$$f^{**}(i_V(v)) = \psi\mapsto  i_V(v)(\psi\circ f) = \psi\mapsto \psi(f(v))=i_W(f(v))\,. $$